# Trato de relacionar dos tablas una llamada requestoring con el campo ID_state y la tabla State con el campo ID_STATE

Tags: laravel, relaciones, livewire

Mi primera relación donde realizamos las relaciones entre las dos tablas

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\estado;
    
    
        public function estado()    
        {
           return $this->hasOne('App\Models\estado', 'ID_STATE');
        }
      
      }
```

la segunda

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\Requestoring;
    
    class estado extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table ='state';
    
        public function requestorings(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Requestoring', 'ID_STATE');
        }
            
    }
```

Y trato de mostrar los datos ya relacionados de la siguiente forma

```
@foreach ($requestorings as $requestoring)
    <tr>
        <td width="10px">{{ $requestoring->ID_REQUESTORIG }}</td>
        <td width="10px">{{ $requestoring->NIT }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-4" width="12px">{{ $requestoring->DES_REQUESTORIG }}</td>
        <td width="10px">{{ $requestoring->DES_AREA }}</td>
        @foreach ($estados as $estado)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$requestoring->ID_STATE}}</td>
                <td>{{$estado->ID_STATE}}</td>
                <td>{{$requestoring->estado->ID_STATE}}</td> 
            </tr>
        @endforeach
                            
        {{-- CREATE BUTTONS --}}
        <td width="10px">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-med float-right" href="{{ route('admin.requestorings.edit', $requestoring) }}">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td width="10px">
            <form action="{{ route('admin.requestorings.destroy', $requestoring) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me presenta el siguiente error

```
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "ID_STATE" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bloodbank\resources\views\livewire\admin\requestorings-index.blade.php)
http://bloodbank.test/admin/requestorings
```

Comment: Igual si agregas la query que construiste se te puede ayudar mas

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor agrega tus migraciones ya que el problema podría estar en la forma como Laravel interpreta tus relaciones